# c# generate thumbnails from raw images

Tags: c#, image, thumbnails

I have an Asp.net Web forms application,when upload raw image file with format

```
 { "cr2", "raw", "dng", "nef", "raf", "orf", "srf", "sr2", "arw", "k25", "kdc", "dcr","mos",
        "pnx", "crw", "mrw", "pef" , "mef" , "rw2","a7","a7r"}
```

How can i generate thumbnails from raw image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dcraw.exe application run on your .net application.you can download it in [the link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcrawnet/).

First save raw image in local disk and use the code:

```
string dcrawPath = "dcraw.exe";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
string inputImagePath= "input Raw Image Path/";
string outputImagePath = "output Raw Image Path/";
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = dcrawPath;
string commandArg1 = string.Format("\"{0}\"", outputImagePath);
string commandArg2 = string.Format("\"{0}\"", inputImagePath);
startInfo.Arguments = "-u ";
startInfo.Arguments += commandArg1;
startInfo.Arguments += " -e ";
startInfo.Arguments += commandArg2;
startInfo.Arguments += " -T";
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
  {
   exeProcess.WaitForExit();
   string stdout = exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   string stderr = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
   Console.WriteLine("Exit code : {0}", exeProcess.ExitCode);
  }
```

Put raw image in inputImagePath variable

You can find image in outputImagePath variable

Answer (score 0):

Try [GDPicture.NET](http://www.gdpicture.com/solutions/supported-formats/) component. It supports different RAW formats and easy for use, but is not free. To generate thumbnail use `CreateThumbnail` or `CreateThumbnailHQ` method of `GdPictureImaging` class:

```
  using (var imaging = new GdPictureImaging())
  {
    int pictureId = imaging.CreateGdPictureImageFromFile(filepath);
    if (pictureId == 0)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Error: " + imaging.GetStat().ToString());
      return;
    }
    int thumbnailImgId = imaging.CreateThumbnail(pictureId, 20, 20);
    imaging.SaveAsPNG(thumbnailImgId, "thumbnail.png");
    imaging.ReleaseGdPictureImage(thumbnailImgId);
    imaging.ReleaseGdPictureImage(pictureId);
  }
```

Comment: @FreeDeveloper: I've added a small code sample to my answer. For more information you can look at their website here [CreateThumbnail](http://guides.gdpicture.com/content/GdPicture.NET.11%20(COM%20-%20ActiveX)~GdPicture11.GdPictureImaging~CreateThumbnail.html) or here [CreateThumbnailHQ](http://guides.gdpicture.com/content/GdPicture.NET.11~GdPicture11.GdPictureImaging~CreateThumbnailHQ(Int32,Int32,Int32,Int32).html)

Comment: i need to generate thumbnail from raw image not .png format

Comment: @FreeDeveloper: Code above takes picture from `filepath` and stores generated thumbnail as .png via `SaveAsPNG`. Of course you can get generated thumbnail as Bitmap: `imaging.GetBitmapFromGdPictureImage(thumbnailImgId)`.